# Forced reboot caused /var/lib/mysql to 'disappear'

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, nginx, database, mariadb

During the nigh my provider had to force reboot the server (pull the plug), after boot, there was a problem with the MySQL server (I'm using MariaDB).

After hours of research I can't find the main source of the problem or any way to solve this. The website is fairly large, deals with Bitcoin, there's thousands of dollars in account balances possibly lost (not really lost, just don't have association to their respective 'owners'), and I'm panicking.

Somehow, the folder /var/lib/mysql 'transformed' into a file with the same name, mysql, it contains gibberish: http://pastebin.com/XbY5YLpG

I've also looked into the log files of MariaDB, and there's several GB of queries in those files.

Is there any possible way I can retrieve the database? I'm very frustrated.

Comment: From your backup, of course.

Comment: I do not have a recent backup.

Comment: You just lost a lot of money, then, and you're likely going out of business, because you didn't do a _lot_ of necessary things (backups being just one of the things you didn't do). Now's a good time to get out of the country before your customers find out...

Comment: I have more than enough funds to pay for every deposit (I can always send them back to the sender, blockchain magic).

Comment: OK, well you probably don't have to flee the country then. Though, I didn't know who you are when I wrote the above.

Comment: were the tables InnoDB or MyISAM?

Answer (score 3):

There is a program [mysqlcheck](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlcheck.html) which ships with mysql that allows you to repair tables, if you can start mysql and your tables are corrupt.  It doesn't sound like that's the case.  There is another program [myisamchk](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisamchk.html), which allows you to ensure the integrity of your MyISAM tables (you weren't using innodb for this, were you?) as long as you have the files relevant to them; it will use their key constraints and journal.

However, since it seems like your filesystem broke and lost the database files, you can't use either of those things.

Even assuming that your data is still there at all (if the directory entry was turned into a file it's possible all references to your files went away and the disk space was reclaimed), if it's in that file you have no way to recover it into a usable format.  If by chance your filesystem can be fixed up and the data was in fact still referenced (use fsck as appropriate for your filesystem), and you can get the files and put them back in the right order, see the first paragraph.

I think you've probably just learned a very expensive lesson, to be honest.  Keep backups!

---

After I wrote this, someone else [found out who you are](http://web.archive.org/web/20140705150202/http://adbit.co/) and [something else related to this](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=449010.msg8400897#msg8400897).  I guess you were keeping backups, and really, you will be needing to restore from those and suffer the loss as uncomfortable as it may be.

If you can't tolerate backups that are even two days old, more frequent backups are one obvious solution; the other solution is to keep live replica sets that you can fail over to (and recover from).  They're like backups, but only work on situations like this (i.e. not on data destruction by malicious hackers, etc.).

You should *especially* keep backups before you move between providers or powercycle servers, if possible.  Also, the symptoms you cited might indicate a bad disk, which would quickly explain much.

Also be aware that if a database is sluggish, chances are very high it is doing some expensive operation like retrying writes or indexing stuff or rebalancing or something.  This is the exact time that a hot reboot will destroy data integrity.

Good luck recovering from this from a business standpoint.  I believe your data past your last backup point is finished.

Another important lesson here is that if you are charging people for something and business continuity is important and data loss is intolerable, you need to build redundancy into your system.  A single node running mysql is, as you've so aptly demonstrated, not sufficiently reliable or redundant.  This is doubly true of a single VPS.  The correct thing to do is to use a VPS provider that allows you to place servers in different places and on different networks explicitly, or eventually buy your own servers and put them in different datacentres.

Comment: Agreed, a replication slave -- that itself is regularly backed up -- would have saved his bacon here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The only option does seem to use the last backup and face a gigantic mess. I'm not trying to hide my identity, I knew someone would end up finding this, otherwise I wouldn't be so specific.

Comment: Yup, not trying to call you out; just drawing on additional background.